# How to set up a router to auto-logout a user after a given time is over

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

I have a hotel where customers can use the WiFi while eating, the problem is that people who had connected to my WiFi earlier at the hotel can still access my WiFi outside the hotel. How can I set up my router so that I can specify a time limit for a particular user and when the time is over it auto-logs them out?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pfsense behind the wireless router. It has a feature called "captive portal" this allows you to get a roll of tickets / numbers to give people with access for a specified time.
The best part is, pfsense is free. And it can be installed on a wide variety of hardware

https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Captive_Portal_Vouchers

Comment: Thanks a lot, Can I run it on a TP Link router?